# C# ASP.NET Int.TryParse method

Tags: c#

```
public string AddToVisa(string s, string s1)
{
    int num;
    int num1;
    Functions con1 = new Functions();
    SqlConnection con = con1.get();
    if (s.Length != 16)
    {

        return "Wrong Details";

    }

        if (!(int.TryParse(s, out num)) || !(int.TryParse(s1, out num1)))
        {
            return "Wrong Visa Details";

        }


    if (s1.Length != 3)
    {
        return "Wrong Visa Details";
    }

    return "Done";
```

The function always returns "Wrong Details" (I tried with these values : s: 1234123412341234 , s1: 123) , The problem is from int.TryParse , When I deleted it the function returned "Done", What's the problem with int.TryParse?

Comment: What does the string "1234123412341234" represent?  Are you attempting to determine if a credit card number is valid?  If so, there is no need to convert to int.  Google for the Luhn algorithm.

Comment: These strings represent credit card numbers, right? So why are you trying to treat them as integers? It doesn't make sense to add credit card numbers together.

Comment: Indeed "-123456789012345" would fit the bill as "a 16 digit value that parses as an integer" but isn't a valid credit card number...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The max value of `int` is `2,147,483,647`. Try use `long`.

```
long num;
var works = long.TryParse(s, out num);
```

Comment: How can I use long method with string and check if it contains only int values ?

Comment: @YamenMassalha: It's very unclear what you're asking, I'm afraid. This has nothing to do with ASP.NET, by the way.

Comment: Oh sorry for that (ASP.NET) :D @JonSkeet

Comment: max value of int: 2,147,483,647. max value of long: 9,223,372,036,854,775,807.

Answer (score 0):

You say *The function always returns "Wrong Details"...* then it seems there is space in your string variable `string s`. Try using `Trim()` before checking the `Length` property like

```
if (s.Trim().Length != 16)
{
    return "Wrong Details";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With new C# 7.0 you can use the following syntax

```
var works = long.TryParse(s, out long num);
```